# Azure SQL Database v12 not working with ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

Recently Microsoft forced the Azure SQL v12 upgrade to our DB and since then all connections through AuthContext (below) takes around 30 seconds to complete.

```
public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public AuthContext():base("SQL"){
   }
}
```

This piece of code..

```
LOG.Info("before create authcontext ");

 var authContext = new AuthContext();

LOG.Info("after create authcontext ");
```

..gets a 28 seconds delay.

```
2015-12-10 17:21:30.880  before new authcontext
2015-12-10 17:21:58.627  after new authcontext
```

Our logger uses the same connection string (SQL) and works fine. We also have another EF6 repo that uses a slighly different connection string that works fine.

Does anyone has any ideas how to solve this??

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the sql user rights.. If I use my "master" account in the connection string it works as expected again. But if I create and use a new user with db_ddladmin, db_owner role it's slow again.

Comment: Are you using contained users, or do you have a login in the master database and a corresponding user in your user database? Contained users are typically faster because they avoid an extra round trip to the master database to authenticate (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff929188.aspx)

Comment: I ended up using contained users instead, cause they didn't have the delay..